# WCF client data over http

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm new to WCF and i created a service that contains a DataContract that is supposed to keep a datamember state but after i call getdata the state i get back is null. Though when i use tcp the value is preseved.

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://KamiServiceHost.net/Go")]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    DataItem GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    void SaveData(DataItem item);
}

 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    private DataItem _item1;
    private DataItem item
    {
        get { return _item1; }
        set { _item1 = value; }
    }

    public void SaveData(DataItem setitem)
    {
        item = setitem;
    }

    public DataItem GetData()
    {
        return item;
    }
}
```

Host app.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Service.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9000"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="Service1" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="Service.IService1"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
 </configuration>
```

client code:

```
  client.Open();
        var dataItem = new DataItem() { Name = "my object", Number = 12 };
        client.SaveData(dataItem);

        var data = client.GetData();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Name: {0}    Number: {1}", data.Name, data.Number));
```

the value of data is null and i have no idea why.. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Web services and Http is stateless. You either need to enable session on your WCF Service and then persist the value of Item in a session and use it or retrieve the item from database based on a filter and return back

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks... but i didn't get what i'm supposed to do i order to make the service preserve the data. Can you please supply a more detailed answer?

Comment: Can you try changing your instanceContext from session to instanceContext.Single.

Answer (score 1):

BasicHttpBinding doesn't support that instance mode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879.aspx. With no session support, the object instance that you provide on the first call is lost

Answer (score 0):

If your service is set to be per instance, then for each call you will get a different instance of your service class on the server, so your returned item will of course be null.